# Disable button after pressed(Beginner) and thought on my program style?

Tags: java

I need help understanding why the buttons and labels wont take effect after i exit my pop up. Its almost like i need to refresh the screen? Earlier i tried coding a label to hold the dogs name and after button has been pressed (Disable button w/I didnt do) and change a label to say label= "Dogname" or Null and the dog name after its pressed example: label = "buddy"

So i achieved this through the code i have below with a textfield text but i want it a label so the user cant erase it and what not.

Why cant i do this with a label?
What is the best way to stay in variable scope? and whats final mean?
When i remove the action listner from the button it still listens.why?
I dont understand initialization and instances very well is there a simple analogy that can help me with this?

New to java and read the books, Tutorials, and guides for help. I cant wait to start programming in my strengths of network knowledge and Mysql for powerful programs. Thx in advance for the help.

This is my first program it generates a unique dog name for the parameters that the users sets. Simple and to the point.

I use the newest java with eclipse.
I coded gui from scratch.
I understand main class and how to implement classes.
The hardest part of java is the gui updating new info and i thought that was going to be the easy part. Seems like adding layouts and panels and frames buttons and have them update with what ur code is doing seems a bit confusing.

Besides long code and neewbie organization, what are some tips to help me learn this? I have put //explaining in my own words what things do and mean and that has helped alot. Any advice will be appreciated greatly.

One last thing to note is i noticed that programmers like to let other newb programmers just "figure it out". In my opinion i dont think that this is as constructive as giving the raw answer and help...I built this program from scratch from a good 4+ tuts and now feel i can program on my own and use the web for help with syntax. I am not looking for anyone to code my project i just need help understanding the basics of this simple application and maybe show me where my code can be better or smaller or faster.

***I know this is all in one class but for example it works better as a simplified version of the program.

Last question: I want to start making a game the is very simple, to help understand java more thoroughly. Text based but with lives and guns and buying and selling ect. What is the best way to set up a program that has multiple variables that need to be updated by multiple classes and those classes have to recognize when the variables are changed from a different class? Hopefully this makes sense.  example johm has 10k cash and is in the baller club but when his cash dips below the 10k mark he is removed from the club. Am i biting off more than i can chew. Next i want to add mysql and online DB's to the mix then graphics buttons ect.

Happy programming~James

```
package petNameGennie;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class FirstGui extends JFrame {
TextField text = new TextField(20);


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public FirstGui(){
    super("Pet Genie");
    setSize(600,400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    JButton b = new JButton("YOLO");

    //adding ears to the button!
    p.add(b);

    add(p);
    add(text);

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("wha");
    JTextField tf= new JTextField("tf     tgggggtg");


    JTextArea ta= new JTextArea("text area yooooo");

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(30,30,30,30);

    //gbc.gridx = 12;
    //gbc.gridy = 12;
    //p3.add(label, gbc);
    //
    //gbc.gridx = 12;
    //gbc.gridy = 12;
    //p3.add(tf, gbc);

    p3.add(label1, gbc);
    p3.add(tf, gbc);
    p3.add(ta);

    add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(p3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(p2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(text, BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            //newgen
            String[] peoples = {"MAX","BUDDY","JAKE","BAILEY");

            List<String> names = Arrays.asList(peoples);
            Collections.shuffle(names);
                {
            int index = new Random().nextInt(names.size());
            String anynames = names.get(index);
            System.out.println(anynames);




            //end gen
            //Auto-generated method stub

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Dogs name is " +    anynames);
            String aa = anynames;
            anynames = aa;

            text.setText(aa);


            }
                }


    }
    );
    //if (b.) {                      //Not complete
        //b.setVisible(false);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need help understanding why the buttons and labels wont take effect
>   after i exit my pop up. Its almost like i need to refresh the screen?
>   Earlier i tried coding a label to hold the dogs name and after button
>   has been pressed (Disable button w/I didnt do) and change a label to
>   say label= "Dogname" or Null and the dog name after its pressed
>   example: label = "buddy"

Replacing `TextField text = new TextField(20);` with `JLabel text = new JLabel();` works just fine for me

> Why cant i do this with a label?

You can and it works fine.  You may need to call `revalidate` to ensure that the parent container is being laid out correctly after the change to the labels text, but it works just fine

> What is the best way to stay in variable scope?

Normally by either using instance variables (like `text`) or passing them as parameters to methods based on what you are trying to achieve.

> and whats final mean?

In the context of variables, `final` essentially means that the memory reference can't be changed at runtime.  Check out [final](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29) for more details

> When i remove the action listner from the button it still listens.why?

I suspect that you are trying to remove the wrong instance of the listener (based on your code example), but you've don't provided code that demonstrates this functionality so it's impossible to tell

> I dont understand initialization and instances very well is there a
>   simple analogy that can help me with this?

You are an instance of Human and your parents initialized you - try not to linger to long on that thought.  Take a look at [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) and [Initializing Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) for more details

> Last question: I want to start making a game the is very simple, to
>   help understand java more thoroughly. Text based but with lives and
>   guns and buying and selling ect. What is the best way to set up a
>   program that has multiple variables that need to be updated by
>   multiple classes and those classes have to recognize when the
>   variables are changed from a different class? Hopefully this makes
>   sense. example johm has 10k cash and is in the baller club but when
>   his cash dips below the 10k mark he is removed from the club. Am i
>   biting off more than i can chew. Next i want to add mysql and online
>   DB's to the mix then graphics buttons ect.

Start by understanding the [Model-View-Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern (and [Understanding Model-View-Controller](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/understanding-model-view-controller.html))

Separate the areas of responsibility so parts of your program have clear and defined areas of responsibility and don't spill over.

Understand the client-server pattern and the areas of responsibility that these two components have.

And code to interface, not implementation.  Take a look at [Code to Interface, Access by name and Instance Data](http://jdevelopment.nl/java-best-practices-5-code-to-interface-access-by-name-and-instance-data/) for some details

Understand [Object Oriented design patterns](http://www.oodesign.com/) and learn when to use them

Comment: Man, What a great answer! Thank you. Analogy was very clear. I used the b.repaint and it updated the button to be removed. Thanks agian for all this great info to read!